# Difference between meta tag content and tag content?

Tags: html

What is the difference between meta tag content and the title ?

I know title will be displayed in the title bar and the meta tag will not be displayed and its for w3 stadards we are just adding it in our html code ...but why we should do that ? what are the uses of it ?  I wish to know detailed and clear explanation about it ...anyone please clear me up

What is the difference between

```
<title>Title of the website</title>
```

AND

```
<meta name="keywords" content="This website is for online shopping" />
```

Comment: I just need definite difference between meta tag content for examples added above

Comment: I just added the example after answering...for that..i don't deserve a down vote ;) peace!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<meta name="keywords" ...>` element has been deprecated (it was never appropriate for what the `<meta>` tag was designed for anyway). From Wikipedia's article on [Meta element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_element#The_keywords_attribute):

> Search engines began dropping support for metadata provided by the `meta` element in 1998, and by the early 2000s, most search engines had veered completely away from reliance on `meta` elements. In July 2002, AltaVista, one of the last major search engines to still offer support, finally stopped considering them.[2]

Comment: Thanks for your time and description Greg..! very much appreciated..!!

Answer (score 0):

Meta elements in HTML can be used for a myriad of things, including linking to other files, like stylesheets or scripts, providing additional information about the content of the page, providing additional instructions to the browser, and much, much more.

A good place to start would be [the Wikipedia entry on meta elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_element) and branch out from the links and sources provided there.